# Alternatives to using .where on ActiveRecord associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using Geocoder gem and can't seem to use `where` to filter a collection of records without losing access to the gem's `.distance` method.

I'm looking for a workaround solution for a query such as:

```
User.includes(:addresses).where("addresses.country = ?", "Poland").references(:addresses)
```

Are there any alternatives to using `where` in this situation? Filtering the records on a simple `find_by` or `find(id)` seems to retain `.distance`, but I don't know how/if this can be used when the condition is on an associated model.

Comment: What do you mean, "losing the gem's methods"?

Comment: Can you name the gem? Maybe some one knows it and can provide help,

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - I can call `Address.near(location).includes(:model)` and the gem allows me to then call `address.distance` on any of the records returned, as it should do. But if I filter the results further using `Address.near(location).includes(:model).where(something)` the `.distance` method appears to stop working.

Comment: @slowjack2k it's on the Geocoder gem - edited question to make it explicit. I tried workaround by calling `.distance_to(location)` but it has to recalculate for each record which is slow and inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`find_by_sql`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql). Here is an example from the linked docs:

```
Post.find_by_sql ["SELECT title FROM posts WHERE author = ? AND created > ?", author_id, start_date]
```

Comment: While it is possible to use that, using SQL immediately reduces the portability of the code and increases the maintenance of it. It's better to try to do it in the ORM itself, not by passing SQL commands. As the documentation says: "The sql parameter is a full SQL query as a string. It will be called as is, there will be no database agnostic conversions performed. This should be a last resort because using, for example, MySQL specific terms will lock you to using that particular database engine or require you to change your call if you switch engines."

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the docs and [github issue 1108](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/1108) for gem `Geocoder` it looks like `distnace` is a method and not a scope. You have to change your code like this:

```
Address.near(location).includes(:model).where(something).each do |address|
  address.distance
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already doing this - only calling `.distance` on each of the individual records, not on the collection.

Comment: Then please provide a sample of your code. If you do it that way and it does not work, then you have found a bug within the gem.